# Empty set of valuations for propositional formulas

Tags: logic

I have read that a set $S$ of formulas logically implies a formula $\phi$ if every valuation of variables that make everything in $S$ true also makes $\phi$ true. What if there are no such valuations that make everything in $S$ true? Would this mean that it vacuously satisfies that condition that the valuations make $\phi$ true?

Comment: if there are no such valuations that make everything in $S$ true then $S$ vacuously implies $\phi$. Your last sentence is a bit vague.

Comment: Would that mean that an empty set of formulas is not independent?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent"?

Comment: That if $S$ is independent then for all $\phi \in S, S-\{\phi\}$ does not logically imply $\phi.$

Comment: Yes. with this definition, an empty set is independent. But note that an empty set implies only tautologies (because any valuation satisfies it).

Comment: If **no** valuation makes all the formulas in $S$ true, this means that $S$ is *unsatisfiable*. Thus, in classical logic, an unsat set of formulas implies every formula (see [Principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no valuations that make everything in $S$ true, we say that $S$ is an inconsistent set of statements. And yes, in such a situation we can say that all valuations that make everything in $S$ true will set $\phi$ to true as well, exactly because there are no such valuations. It would be like saying that every time I played the lottery, I won the jackpot, which is true exactly because I never played the jackpot. So yes, an inconsistent set of statements implies any statement, including both $\phi$ and $\neg \phi$.